# Adding a class with jQuery to first and last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following to add a class with js:

```js
$('.image-container img:first').addClass('active');
$('.image-container img:last').addClass('left');
```

```css
.active { border: 1px solid red; }
.left { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='image-container'>
  <img src="/img.png" alt="xga-1">
  <br>
  <img src="/img2.png" alt="xga-1">
</div>
```

When I add the class active or left dynamically, it also add the class to the `<br>` tags in between the images. How I prevent the code to do that and only add the class to the images inside `image-container`?

Comment: are you sure? Please, create an evidence. At the moment your code works fine.

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet. As you can see it works fine. There is nothing about your code that would apply any classes on a `br` element. If that is happening it must be due to another area of your code

Comment: Yup, everything I'm seeing does exactly what you seem to want. Also, why are you using br tags at all and not simply using CSS to display them as block elements?

Comment: Can you reproduce it using your snippet? Any particular browser you're testing it on?

Comment: Your code runs fine as it. No class is added to the `<br>` element.

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference, but use `$('.image-container').find('img:first').addClass('active')` instead, it is a much better selector and can have performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the "not" function in JQuery to accomplish this 
http://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$('.image-container img:first').not("br").addClass('active');
$('.image-container img:last').not("br").addClass('left');
```

Although that is odd that that is happening at all but this should at least rule out whether or not this bit of code is the cause.

Comment: But before to provide an answer, why you don't verify that the issue described by the user is not happening?

Comment: I did run the snippet and clearly its not happening as far I can see but it was to OP in his environment. Adding this code can help rule out that this bit of code as the problem. More than likely it's somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('.image-container img').first().addClass('active');
    $('.image-container img').last().addClass('left');
```

```css
 .active { border: 1px solid red; }
    .left { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='image-container'>
      <img src="/img.png" alt="xga-1">
      <br>
      <img src="/img2.png" alt="xga-1">
    </div>
```

Comment: But before to provide an answer, why you don't verify that the issue described by the user is not happening?